# How to avoid repetition of dictionary in a list using random function in python?

Tags: python-3.x, random

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import random
import shutil
from pathlib import Path

def sample() -> None:
    number_of_iteration = int(input("Enter the number of iterations for file generation\n"))
    choice_of_random = int(input("Enter 0 to run A Scenarios and 1 to run B Scenarios\n"))
    for i in range(1, number_of_iteration + 1):
        my_dir = Path(f"/home/user1/Iteration{i}")
        my_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        file_name = f"file_name" + '.txt'

        path_to_master_MakeFile = Path(f"/home/user1/MasterMakeFile") #Path to MakeFile outside the test directory
        with (my_dir / file_name).open('w') as f:
            needed_dicts = [dict_1, dict_2, dict_3, dict_4, dict_5]

            # Randomization for IDPT Scenarios
            if choice_of_random == 0:
                random_dict = random.sample(needed_dicts, k=1)[0]
                for key, value in dict_0.items():
                    f.write(key + '\n')
                    for key1, value1 in value.items():
                        f.write(f"{key1} :={value1}\n")
                    f.write(f"{'}'}")
                    f.write(f"\n\n")
                for key, value in random_dict.items():
                    f.write(key + '\n')
                    for key1, value1 in value.items():
                        f.write(f"{key1} :={value1}\n")
                    f.write(f"{'}'}")
                    f.write(f"\n\n")
                for key_dict, value_dict in MAIN_DICT.items():
                    f.write(key_dict + '\n')
                    for key1, value1 in value_dict.items():
                        f.write(f"{key1} :={value1}\n")
                    f.write(f"{'}'}")
                    f.write(f"\n\n")
            shutil.copy("/home/user1/Makefile", my_dir)  # To copy MakeFile into the Iteration Directories
            shutil.copy("/home/user1/some_filename.cpp", my_dir)  # To copy .cpp file into the Iteration Directories
            shutil.copy("/home/user1/Makefile", path_to_master_MakeFile)


dict_0 = {
    'DICT_0 {': {
        'color': "pink;"
            }
        }

dict_1 = {
    'DICT_1 {': {
        'color': "red;"
            }
        }
dict_2 = {
    'DICT_2 {': {
        'color': "green;"
            }
        }
dict_3 = {
    'DICT_3 {': {
        'color': "blue;"
            }
        }
dict_4 = {
    'DICT_4 {': {
        'color': "orange;"
            }
        }
dict_5 = {
    'DICT_5 {': {
        'color': "violet;"
            }
        }
MAIN_DICT = {
    'MAIN_DICT {' : {
        'color': "gray;"
    }
 }

sample()
```

This is my code, it has 5 dictionaries (dict_1, dict_2, dict_3, dict_4, dict_5) assigned to variable needed_dicts list. Each of these dictionaries needed to be written to file_name.txt. To each file dict_0 and MAIN_DICT has to be always written, but the code has to randomly choose one dict among dict_1, dict_2, dict_3, dict_4, dict_5. The above writen code it doing that, but when I code prompts "Enter the number of iterations for file generation" and i give 5, then in 5 files dict_1 is being written 2 times and dict_2 is written for 2 times and dict_3 is being written for 1 time. I want the code to randomly choose any of those 5 dictionaries and write it to the file without repetation and should be unique.
For ex - If I give 5 as input to "Enter the number of iterations for file generation" to file 1 it can write dict_4, for file 2 it can write dict_3, for file 3 it can write dict_1, for file 4 it can write dict_2 and for file 5 it can write dict_5. Please help me to modify the above code in this way.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you described this works. I removed some useless controls from your file since I don't need them.

I put the dictionary elements in a list that I shuffle every 5 times and iterate it

```
import random
import shutil
from pathlib import Path
import itertools

def sample() -> None:
    number_of_iteration = int(input("Enter the number of iterations for file generation\n"))
    choice_of_random = int(input("Enter 0 to run A Scenarios and 1 to run B Scenarios\n"))
    needed_dicts = [dict_1, dict_2, dict_3, dict_4, dict_5]

    # Shuffle the list of other dictionaries
    random.shuffle(needed_dicts)

    # Use itertools.cycle to cycle through the shuffled dictionaries
    dictionaries_cycle = itertools.cycle(needed_dicts)

    for i in range(1, number_of_iteration + 1):
        my_dir = Path(f"/home/user1/Iteration{i}")
        my_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        file_name = f"file_name" + '.txt'

        # Randomization for IDPT Scenarios
        if choice_of_random == 0:
            path_to_master_MakeFile = Path(f"/home/user1/MasterMakeFile")  # Path to MakeFile outside the test directory
            with (my_dir / file_name).open('w') as f:
                # Always write DICT_0 first
                for key, value in dict_0.items():
                    f.write(key + '\n')
                    for key1, value1 in value.items():
                        f.write(f"{key1} :={value1}\n")
                    f.write(f"{'}'}")
                    f.write(f"\n\n")

                if i > 5:
                    # After the first 5 iterations, shuffle the list of dictionaries again
                    random.shuffle(needed_dicts)
                    dictionaries_cycle = itertools.cycle(needed_dicts)

                # Write one of the shuffled dictionaries (or cycle through them)
                current_dict = next(dictionaries_cycle)
                for key, value in current_dict.items():
                    f.write(key + '\n')
                    for key1, value1 in value.items():
                        f.write(f"{key1} :={value1}\n")
                    f.write(f"{'}'}")
                    f.write(f"\n\n")

                # Write MAIN_DICT last
                for key, value in MAIN_DICT.items():
                    f.write(key + '\n')
                    for key1, value1 in value.items():
                        f.write(f"{key1} :={value1}\n")
                    f.write(f"{'}'}")
                    f.write(f"\n\n")

        shutil.copy("/home/user1/Makefile", my_dir)  # To copy MakeFile into the Iteration Directories
        shutil.copy("/home/user1/some_filename.cpp", my_dir)  # To copy .cpp file into the Iteration Directories
        shutil.copy("/home/user1/Makefile", path_to_master_MakeFile)

dict_0 = {
    'DICT_0 {': {
        'color': "pink;"
    }
}

dict_1 = {
    'DICT_1 {': {
        'color': "red;"
    }
}
dict_2 = {
    'DICT_2 {': {
        'color': "green;"
    }
}
dict_3 = {
    'DICT_3 {': {
        'color': "blue;"
    }
}
dict_4 = {
    'DICT_4 {': {
        'color': "orange;"
    }
}
dict_5 = {
    'DICT_5 {': {
        'color': "violet;"
    }
}
MAIN_DICT = {
    'MAIN_DICT {': {
        'color': "gray;"
    }
}

sample()
```

Try it and let me know :)

EDIT: I added the choice_of_random choice

Comment: Thanks for the help buddy! With ur code I was facing current_dict' referenced before assignment error at line 36 so i made the following modifications (in the next comment)

Comment: `if choice_of_random == 0:
                if i <= 5:  #when i<5 I was only getting MAIN_DICT & DICT_0 being written in the file and any other dict from dict_1 to dict_5 wasnt getting written
                # After the first 5 iterations, shuffle the list of dictionaries again
                    random.shuffle(needed_dicts)
                    dictionaries_cycle = itertools.cycle(needed_dicts)
            # Write one of the shuffled dictionaries
                    current_dict = next(dictionaries_cycle)
                    for key, value in current_dict.items():`

Comment: `f.write(key + '\n')
                        for key1, value1 in value.items():
                            f.write(f"{key1} :={value1}\n")
                        f.write(f"{'}'}")
                        f.write(f"\n\n") `

Comment: With the above changes I'm unable to get all 5 dictionaries written to each of the 5 files. I just ran the code & gave the number of iterations as 5,in the 1st file i got dict_1 & in 2nd file i got dict_2, dict_4 in 3rd file, AGAIN dict_1 in 4th file and AGAIN dict_1 in 5th file, I dont want this repetation, randomly in whatever order those dictionaries can be written to the file but there shouldn't be this kind of repetation is what I'm expecting mate. If u could help it will be really helpful.& also I need that choice_of_random variable bcz i have some other running for choice_of_random == 1

Comment: I changed the code to add the choice_of_random variable, can you run it and let me know what's the error?